# Eclipse Plugin Development : How to add option in Right Click Menu

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have created an eclipse plugin. I am able to add a menu and submenu.

However, I am not able to add an option in the Right Click menu. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Related: [Custom Popup menu in eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34987377/3744182).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example (this code has filled with your preferences and classes and to be added to the plugin.xml):

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus"> 
    <objectContribution
      adaptable="true"
      id=""
      nameFilter=""
      objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
      <action
         id="org.eclipse.ui.articles.action.contribution.object.action1" 
         label=""
         icon=""
         menubarPath="additions"
         class=""> 
      </action>
    </objectContribution>
</extension>
```

Comment: However, I am not able to see the option when I right click on the current editor window. I see it only when I right click on the .java file in Navigator mode.

Answer (score 2):

The provided solution using `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` is deprecated.
One should use the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point.

In general you can configure a `menuContribution` using the plugin GUI, which will generate the `plugin.xml` for you. As you requested the menu to be available in the "Right Click menu" you can use `popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any` as **locationURI**. With additional configuration you can control under which circumstances the menu should be visible.
[image: Eclipse plugin configuration GUI]

You can also edit the `plugin.xml` directly in the plugin.xml tab.
The generated `plugin.xml` will look similar to this:

```xml
<extension
    id="menuid"
    point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any">
        .
        .
        .
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

See [Custom Popup menu in eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987377/custom-popup-menu-in-eclipse-plugin) for a similar problem.