# Custom Popup menu in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my current project, I have created **popup menus using eclipse plugin**. Following is the code of **plugin.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
 <?eclipse version="3.0"?>
 <plugin>
<extension point="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.generated_package">
        <package 
        uri = "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"
        class = "org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.MyDslPackage"
        genModel = "model/generated/MyDsl.genmodel" />          
</extension>
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus"> 
      <objectContribution
      id="org.xtext.example.mydsl.contribution1"
      objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">           

   <menu
         id="org.xtext.example.mydsl.menu1"
         label="IoTSuite Compilation"
         path="additions">             
      <separator
            name="group1">
      </separator>
   </menu>                 
   <visibleWhen
          checkEnabled="false">
       <iterate
             ifEmpty="false"
             operator="or">
              <test
                property="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"
                value="vocab.mydsl">
        <action
        class="org.xtext.example.mydsl.popup.actions.CompileVocabSpec"
         enablesFor="1"
         id="org.xtext.example.mydsl.newAction"
         label="Compile Vocab.mydsl"
         menubarPath="org.xtext.example.mydsl.menu1/group1">
   </action> 
                </test>
       </iterate>
    </visibleWhen>           

   <action
         class="org.xtext.example.mydsl.popup.actions.CompileArchSpec"
         enablesFor="1"
         id="org.xtext.example.mydsl.newAction"
         label="Compile Arch.mydsl"
         menubarPath="org.xtext.example.mydsl.menu1/group1">
   </action>
   <action
         class="org.xtext.example.mydsl.popup.actions.CompileInteractionSpec"
         enablesFor="1"
         id="org.xtext.example.mydsl.newAction"
         label="Compile Interaction.mydsl"
         menubarPath="org.xtext.example.mydsl.menu1/group1">
   </action>
   <action
         class="org.xtext.example.mydsl.popup.actions.CompileDeploySpec"
         enablesFor="1"
         id="org.xtext.example.mydsl.newAction"
         label="Compile Deploy.mydsl"
         menubarPath="org.xtext.example.mydsl.menu1/group1">
   </action>  

</objectContribution>
```

When I run above eclipse plugin application, it displays popup-menu as follows.[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlaHE.png). The problem is, as shown in image I have four files **vocab.mydsl, arch.mydsl, userinteraction.mydsl and deploy.mydsl** and also **four actions (Compile Vocab.mydsl, Compile Arch.mydsl, Compile Interaction.mydsl and Compile Deploy.mydsl )** under a popup menu. Now I want to **customize action** in such way that, when I click on **vocab.mydsl** then it should **display only Compile Vocab.mydsl** as an action in popup menu similarly when I click in arch.mydsl than it should display only Compile Arch.mydsl etc. I have made changes as per suggestion, but it display error like `MESSAGE Plugin org.xtext.example.mydsl, extension org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus: Unknown extension tag found: visibleWhen`. Am I missing something ??

**Edit**
Finally  partial problem is solved using comment. Content of updated plugin.xml file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
     <menuContribution
    allPopups="false"
    locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
    <command
       commandId="org.xtext.example.mydsl.popup.actions.CompileVocabSpec"
         defaultHandler="org.xtext.example.mydsl.popup.actions.CompileVocabSpec" 
       label="Compile Vocab"
       style="push">
        <visibleWhen
          checkEnabled="false">
       <iterate
             ifEmpty="false"
             operator="or">
          <test
                property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                value="vocab.mydsl">
          </test>
       </iterate>
    </visibleWhen>
 </command>

  <command              
         commandId="org.xtext.example.mydsl.popup.actions.CompileArchSpec"
         defaultHandler="org.xtext.example.mydsl.popup.actions.CompileArchSpec"  
       label="Compile Arch"
       style="push">
        <visibleWhen
          checkEnabled="false">
       <iterate
             ifEmpty="false"
             operator="or">
          <test
                property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                value="arch.mydsl">
          </test>
       </iterate>
    </visibleWhen>
 </command>
 </menuContribution>
  </extension>
 </plugin>
```

I am very new to this eclipse plugin development. When I fired **Compile Vocab command** than it should **performed action** mentioned in `CompileVocabSpec.java`. The content of `CompileVocabSpec.java` is as below:

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.popup.actions;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IAction;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.IActionDelegate;
import org.eclipse.ui.IObjectActionDelegate;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart;

public class CompileVocabSpec implements IObjectActionDelegate {

private Shell shell;

/**
 * Constructor for Action1.
 */
public CompileVocabSpec() {
    super();
}

/**
 * @see IObjectActionDelegate#setActivePart(IAction, IWorkbenchPart)
 */
@Override
public void setActivePart(IAction action, IWorkbenchPart targetPart) {
    shell = targetPart.getSite().getShell();
}

/**
 * @see IActionDelegate#run(IAction)
 */
@Override
public void run(IAction action) {

    String[] args = new String[3];
    args[0] = "compile-vocab-spec";
    args[1] = "C:/Template/";

    // Call to Main method in ToolSuite
    try {
        // Main.main(args);
        System.out.println("Compilation of Vocab");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ;

}

/**
 * @see IActionDelegate#selectionChanged(IAction, ISelection)
 */
@Override
public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
}
```

}

Here when I fired Compile Vocab command it doesn't performed any action. Am I missing something ??

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` is deprecated and has been for a long time. You can only set visibility for the entire `objectContribution` and I don't think you can specify a single file name. Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point which can do this.

Comment: @greg-449 - could you please elaborate more on  org.eclipse.ui.menus ??. It will be grateful for me.

Comment: Read something like http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html

Comment: @greg-449- Thnx for the pointer. I have gone through article suggested by you. But I am not able to dig out, how to solve problem mentioned in question??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` is deprecated and has been for a long time. You can only set visibility for the entire objectContribution and I don't think you can specify a single file name.

The `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point allows visibility of individual commands to be controlled.

For example:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any">
     <command
           commandId="test.command"
           label="Command Vocab"
           style="push">
        <visibleWhen
              checkEnabled="false">
           <iterate
                 ifEmpty="false"
                 operator="or">
              <test
                    property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                    value="vocab.mydsl">
              </test>
           </iterate>
        </visibleWhen>
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

The `visibleWhen` element is restricting the visibility to just the 'vocab.mydsl' file.

Comment: @greg-449- What should I write in place of property of test attribute ?? I am not getting that point.

Comment: You can't just use the visibleWhen in your `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point, you have to convert **completely** to using  `org.eclipse.ui.menus`.

Comment: @greg-449- Thank you  for the pointer. Now partial problem is solved with your help. Now question is how to add action when I fired command ??

Comment: That is covered in the tutorial I referenced. You need to use the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` and `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` extension points.